# Hyphens and Jsoup Error

Tags: java, jsoup, special-characters

I have a web scraper and I get an error with the hyphen. I searched online and saw a lot of errors related to hyphens but there were no clear ways for the issue to be solved.

Here is the code:

```
       try{
            int t = 25 * 1000;
            this.jDoc = Jsoup
                    .connect(url)
                    .userAgent(
                            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0")
                    .maxBodySize(0).timeout(t).get();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            this.jDoc = null;
        }
```

The error:

```
crawling url = http://www.wida-handel.de/Oventrop/OventrPumpengr--Regumat-
error url = http://www.wida-handel.de/Oventrop/OventrPumpengr--Regumat-
jsoup error org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL.      
Status=404, URL=http://www.wida-handel.de/Oventrop/OventrPumpengr--Regumat-
```

The Url is invalid and I think the error is caused by the hyphen not being understood.

Does anyone have any ideas about the solution for this error?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.wida-handel.de/Oventrop/OventrPumpengr--Regumat-")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0")
                    .maxBodySize(0).timeout(t).ignoreHttpErrors(true).get();
```

the result

[image]

Comment: Would ignoring errors still get the content? The system now is saying 404 so it seems to me the system will just get null in the document.

Comment: when  http 404 is returned, the jsoup will terminate and throw an exception, but the 404 do not represent no content from server

Comment: I did testing and the system still returns 404. I am unsure how you had it working.

Comment: try the following code   Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.wida-handel.de/Oventrop/OventrPumpengr--Regumat-")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0")
                    .maxBodySize(0).timeout(t).ignoreHttpErrors(true).get(); System.out.println(doc.text())

Comment: I tried that, and it is not handling the document, maybe there is an error somewhere else. It is crashing on a 404 error.

Comment: the jsoup version is 1.8.1 in my app